# Error (sqlite3*) database object in array

Tags: ios, sqlite

Good Day All!

I have a problem regarding with inserting/storing an sqlite3 object in array. I have this method in implementation:

```
-(void)addDatabase:(sqlite3*)database databaseName:(NSString*)language inLocation:(NSString*)locationPath {
    // add database to array of databases
    if ([language length] > 0) {
        [[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"object"] addObject:database];
        [[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"language"] addObject:language];
        [[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"location"] addObject:locationPath];
    }

    //TODO: add db
}
```

In here: `[[self.openDatabases objectForKey:@"object"] addObject:database];` I always have an error. Its like it not accept an sqlite3 object.

This is my declaration of that object:

```
ATIDatabase.h
@property sqlite3 *database;

ATIDatabase.m
@synthesize database = _database;
```

I'm stuck with this. I'm new in IOS Programming.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Objective-C objects can be stored in Objective-C collection classes, and `sqlite3` is not an Objective-C object.

I would create a custom object, containing all the database attributes, and simply use an array of those.  This will be way more useful than an array of dictionaries.

Database.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Database : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) sqlite3 *database;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *language;
@property (nonatomic) NSURL *path;

- (id)initWithDatabase:(sqlite *)database
              language:(NSString *)language
                  path:(NSURL *)path;

@end
```

Database.m:

```
#import "Database.h"

@implementation Database

- (id)initWithDatabase:(sqlite *)database
              language:(NSString *)language
                  path:(NSURL *)path
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.database = database;
        self.language = language;
        self.path = path;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And once you have an object like that, you can start abstracting your database operations by adding methods to that class (and once you start doing that you'll probably realise you need a `Statement` object counterpart; but I digress).

**EDIT** Update at OP's request.

So the new version of the method you post would be (note I've changed the parameter names and switched from using `NSString` to `NSURL` for the path.  Also I've assumed `self.openDatabases` is an `NSMutableArray`).

```
-(void)addDatabase:(sqlite3 *)database
          language:(NSString *)language
        inLocation:(NSURL *)path
{
    Database *db = [[Database alloc] initWithDatabase:database
                                             langauge:language
                                                 path:path];
    [self.openDatabases addObject:db];

    //TODO: add db
}
```

Comment: but can you give me an example how to put those objects in an nsmutablearray?